# JDBCHDFS job failed with Filesystem closed exception

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

We tried following jdbchdfs job in current environment

Our environment is:
spring-xd version :1.2.1
hadoop distribution : PHD3.0

```
job create rcd_prod --definition "jdbchdfs --driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --url='jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:49552;database=databasename' --username=User --password=xxxxxx --testOnBorrow=false --delimiter=^ --sql='select * from tablename' --fsUri=hdfs://HOSTNAME-HA --fileExtension=csv --directory=/PATH/TO/DIR/ --fileName=XYZ --partitions=1 --makeUnique=true"
```

Getting error on execution of jdbchdfs job

Following Error

```
java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1423)
    at org.springframework.xd.batch.item.hadoop.AbstractHdfsItemWriter.initializeCounterIfNecessary(AbstractHdfsItemWriter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.xd.batch.item.hadoop.HdfsTextItemWriter.write(HdfsTextItemWriter.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletSte
```

What is causing this exception and how can we fix this?

Comment: Please, suggest where  lacking while  submitting question ! so, that it is more readable !

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually encountered when you're running multiple jdbchdfs jobs. The thing is core Hadoop library closes the connections for the entire JVM - so any jobs running parallel and have opened HDFS files may close each other's file system connection.

This has been fixed from 1.3.1.RC.

http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/pull/1805

Comment: Thanks for reply. We have two parallel job both running at same time using cron. But only it executs one job  and other completly failed. Do we have any way so that our both job run parallel without fail.and one more thing i observed if i ran diffrent job so  my both jobs fails  on first run of cron.Looking forward  about how to avoid failure of job on each run.

Comment: can you run in distributed mode? try deploying to different containers in that way you will have 2 separate JVMs.

Comment: Spring XD team just fixed this - you may see it resolved in the next release.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/pull/1805

Comment: Thanks for fixed link.  I have deployed to diffrent containers using following commands : job deploy hdfsjob1 --properties "module.jdbchdfs.criteria=host.equals('host1.acme.com')"
job deploy hdfsjob2 --properties "module.jdbchdfs.criteria=host.equals('host2.acme.com')"

Comment: While running multiple parallel job. job failure  event is normal in this version. is that possible to have  different xd-shell admin-ui account ? so, in that way we may run development and production batch  job without interruption ? Any help on it  would be much appreciated ?

Comment: what do you mean by different xd-shell accounts? how does your setup look like? do you have a common xd-cluster for production/development jobs? if yes, then you may create container groups, and then deploying to the container you can provide deployment properties - similar to the way you gave criteria for host name. This way you will have separate groups for dev and prod and know at deployment time what group are you deploying your job.

Comment: We are using spring xd distributed runtime architecture. install via ambari plugin.